# Falsy values in if -statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been working this JavaScript thing at school for a while during last two weeks, and I'm stucked with my homework.

In the book "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford the author lists the falsy values in the if -statement on the page 11. Now I'm trying  to test user's input from the html form for a input returning false in  the case statement. But there's something really badly got wrong, I suppose. Here's my code. Can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>My JavaScript Page</title>

<!--JavaScript starts here-->

<script>
function test() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    switch (input){
    case false:
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False"
    break;
    case typeof() == "null":
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False"
    break;
        case typeof() == "undefined":
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False"
    break;
        case '':
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False"
    break;
        case "0":
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False"
    break;
        case isNan():
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False"
    break;
    default : document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "True"
    }
} 

</script>


<!--End of JavaScript-->

</head>
<body>
<h1>True or False in JavaScipt</h1>
<form>
Your Input: <input type="text" id="userInput">
<br>
<button type="button" value="Test" onClick="test()">Test!</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<p id="result"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, that isn't syntactically valid. You have to use a value with `typeof` (ex: `typeof input`). Open your console (hit F12) to see said errors. Also, everything you extract from `text` input will come back as a `string`. The only way you'll get a falsy value that way is if they enter nothing. If they type in "false" you'll get `"false"` not `false`.

Comment: Yep, there's awful syntax errors in my code. I can't find the right wrapper -function for a parsing the string input that I could check if it false or true.

Comment: You could just do a check: `if (input === "false") { input = false; }` Same idea with `true`.

Comment: That's how I probably would do it if this wasn't my homework. The teacher wants us to program this using case -statement.

Comment: As you can tell from @Barmar's answer, you *must* do the conversion otherwise it will always be a string and I'm sure that's not what your teacher wants (unless they only care about the truthiness of strings).

Comment: You are not going to be able to solve a problem if you are unable to get your syntax correct first of all.  Either ask a question about how to write the syntax (or google it) or get the syntax correct first and then ask a question about the logic.

Answer (score 1):

The value after `case` has to be something that might be equal to the value in the `switch()` statement, i.e.

```
case x:
```

is similar to:

```
if (input == x) {
```

You can't put comparisons there, and expect it to insert `input` into the appropriate part of it.

Instead of `switch`, you need to use `if`.

```
if (input === false) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
} else if (typeof(input) == "null") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
} else if (typeof(input) == "undefined") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
} else if (input === "") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
} else if (input === "0") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
} else if (isNaN(input)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "True";
}
```

Since all of the cases are doing the same thing, you can combine them with the OR operator `||`:

```
if (input === false || typeof(input) == "null" || typeof(input) == "undefined" || input === "" || input === "0" || isNaN(input)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "True";
}
```

Note, by the way, that if you're trying to identify all the falsy values, your `"0"` case is wrong. The only string that's falsy is the empty string `""`. The **number** `0` is falsy, but not the string `"0"`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy for a complete list of all the falsy values in Javascript.

Comment: would *any* of the `else if` statements ever be executed?

Comment: @JaromandaX `input == "0"` can be executed. The only string that's falsy is `""`.

Comment: I've changed the answer to use `===`, so it will do exact comparisons like `switch`.